# jQuery. Mouse hover each button to adjust opacity and show images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When the mouse is placed over each button, the opacity is adjusted and the image is coded to appear. Mouse over each current button changes the corresponding image. However, errors occur when adjusting opacity. The following is my code. The code in the annotation does not change the image. How can I solve this?
I've never learned J-Query before, so I wrote it with reference. That's why I need help.

```
<!-- 브라우저 실행 : ALT+B -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>second_test</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="second_web.css">
    <link rel="script" href="second_web.js"> -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          r(); 
          b();
          c();
        });
        // hover image change
        function r(){
          $('.hz').css('display','none'); $('.r').css('display','block');  $('.r')
        }
        function b(){
          $('.hz').css('display','none'); $('.b').css('display','block');  $('.r')
        }
        function c(){
          $('.hz').css('display','none'); $('.c').css('display','block');  $('.r')
        }
        // hover image opacity 0 -> 1
        // if. food img -> indoor img change
        // > food img(0), imdoor img (1)
        // else if. indoor img -> food img change
        // > food img (1), imdoor img (0)
        // $('.c').fadeIn(500,function(){
        //     $('.hz').css('display','none'); $('.c').css('display','block');
        // });
        </script>
    <style>
        .hz {
            width:800px; height:600px;
        }
        .r {
            background-image: url(./food.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
        } 
        .b {
            background-image: url(./indoor.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .c {
            background-image: url(./outdoor.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="./first_web.html">back</a>
    <div class="hz r"></div>
    <div class="hz b"></div>
    <div class="hz c"></div>
    <button onmouseover="r()">food</button>
    <button onmouseover="b()">indoor</button>
    <button onmouseover="c()">outdoor</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

It's a function that I wanted to make.

1. Mouse on button changes image, does not change.
2. I want to change from transparent to opaque when the image changes, giving a smooth transition effect.
3. Removing the mouse from the button does not change the image.
   For example, if button 1 has an A image and button 2 has a B image,
   When button 2 is hover and removed, image B remains the same.

[buttonhover_img_change_not opacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiKOg.gif)

[Not a smooth transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYeRo.gif)

Comment: PS: the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration should be the first line of your document. Avoid using comments in there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but here's a different version of what I believe might work for you.

Basically, you create a CSS class and add/remove it from the elements based on `mouseover` or `mouseout`

See sample code below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // init: show the first image (under ".r")
  $('.hz').removeClass('show');
  $('.r').addClass('show');

  // when hovering over the button, add the class to show opacity
  $("button").on('mouseover', function() {
    var btnId = $(this).attr("id");
    //    console.log(btnId);
    $('.hz').removeClass('show hover');
    $('.' + btnId).addClass('show hover');

  });

  // when exiting hover mode over the button, remove the class to remove opacity
  $("button").on('mouseout', function() {
    var btnId = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.' + btnId).removeClass('hover');
  });
});
```

```css
.hz {
  min-width: 350px;
  min-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hz:hover, 
.hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.r {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
}

.b {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
}

.c {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/301);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="./first_web.html">back</a>
<div class="hz r"></div>
<div class="hz b"></div>
<div class="hz c"></div>
<button id="r">food</button>
<button id="b">indoor</button>
<button id="c">outdoor</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I adjusted opacity and transition on CSS, it feels like I want it, but it keeps breaking off and not smooth. How do I modify the code? I added a picture of it cutting off.

.hover {
          opacity: 1;
          transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
        }